# creating cronjob that cancel orders that are older than 24 hours

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, order-status, cronjobs

I want to  execute cronjob if the orders are 24 hours old and and turning pending payment status to cancel. how to do that?

I have this code script but doesn't want to work the way it suppose to, what did i miss?

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$time = time();
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);
$lastTime = $time - 86400;
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastTime);
$orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> 'pending_payment'])
                        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', [
                            'from' => $from,
                            'to' => $to 
                        ])
                        ->load();
                        
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderState = 'canceled';
    $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus($orderState);
    $order->save();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

Can refer `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/MassCancel.php` file which is used to cancel order from Admin!

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

$time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-1 day"));

$orders = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory')->create()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['eq'=> 'pending_payment'])
                        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lt'=> $time])
                        ->load();

$orderManagement = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface');
                        
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    try {
        $orderManagement->cancel($order->getEntityId());
        echo "order with Id =".$order->getId()." is canceled" .PHP_EOL;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return __('cannot cancel the order');
    }
}
```

Hope above will help!

Comment: time() method is not working it only cancel orders that are placed today which i don't want. i want to cancel all orders that are 24 hours old with a pending payment status

Comment: I have updated code, $time will get last order greater than last 24 hours

Comment: i have edited the code i put 'lt'=> $time it working for me rather than 'gt'=> $time and i added "PHP_EOL" in the code please check

Comment: Approved your updates..I was checking and modified code as per my orders data..forgot to update!now it is fine...

Comment: you can accept answer as well!

Comment: i did accept the answer

Comment: thanks @Bayzel FYI you just upvote answer..there is right tick below answer to accept the answer :)